# RSpec test ArgumentError: When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am trying to run the following test for one of my models:

```
let(:customer) { create :customer }
let(:ticket) { create :ticket, reserved_by: customer }
let(:order) { Order.new(customer: customer, ticket_order_tickets: [ticket]) }

it 'creates the ticket order with the correct ticket' do
  expect(order.ticket_orders.first.ticket).to be ticket
end
```

With this code in my model to assign the `ticket_order_tickets`:

```
def ticket_order_tickets=(tickets_for_ticket_orders)
  tickets_for_ticket_orders.each do |ticket|
    ticket_orders.build(ticket) if ticket.reserved_by?(customer)
  end
end
```

But when I run the test, I get the following error:

```
Failure/Error: let(:order) { Order.new(customer: customer, ticket_order_tickets: tickets) }
     ArgumentError:
       When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `each` block in `ticket_order_tickets` is calling `build` on the `ticket_orders` relation passing in whatever's in `tickets_for_ticket_orders`. In your setup, it's single item array containing an actual Ticket, and `build` (like `create`) expects a Hash of attributes. That seems to be the issue.